# Django on Google App Engine - No module named PIL._imaging

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-storage, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to use the cloudstorage from Google App Engine together with Django 1.8 (via Djangae, although that shouldn't be relevant here). I am mostly trying to get file upload via the admin to work.

When actually deployed everything works fine, I can upload files without problems. When running the same things locally however I get the following import error from PIL's Image.py.

`No module named PIL._imaging`

In this setup Django uses a local sitepackages folder where PIL and Pillow is installed, which seems to be part of the problem. If just run python directly in the terminal (after installing them globally) I can import _imaging just fine.

Any ideas? This is on OSX El Capitan and I have some people saying that might be related to similar issues, but nothing I have found so far has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/), you get to use a wrapped "images API":

```
from google.appengine.api import images
```

Google's `images` API then makes use of PIL or Pillow on the backend. If I were you, I'd try using `google.appengine.api.images`, not PIL directly. Then you'd be using the document, *correct* API.

However if you swear that using PIL directly works on production, you might be able to finagle it to work locally by "whitelisting" its c library portion. You can do this:

```
PRODUCTION_MODE = not os.environ.get(
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'Development').startswith('Development')
if not PRODUCTION_MODE:
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox
    sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += YOUR_MODULE_LIST
```

In YOUR_MODULE_LIST, you'll have to figure out what C modules are part of your PIL installation.

But again, the way to go is to use Google's API, not try to directly use PIL.

Comment: If that was the case I would get an error when trying to import PIL, which is not the case. The error occurs inside PIL when it tries to use a c library.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The docs actually have you using a wrapped API, while you're using PIL directly. You could try whitelisting the C module, but you should probably consider using the provided API. I'm updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KenKinder the docs actually say PIL is supported https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need to request any supported third-party libraries in your app.yaml file.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

To run locally, you would need to install the PIL package using pip.